# What is the meaning of 'like' in this context?

Tags: lyrics

I was listening to a song by Kamelot; you can find the lyrics [here](http://www.azlyrics.com/lyrics/kamelot/mourningstar.html). However, I can't understand the meaning of 'like' where it's used:

> Tell me when the night is gone,
>
> Like washed away,
>
> Make a wish beneath the mourning star.

Does it mean to emphasize the humanity's extinction? As in, "not just gone, but like, washed away.", or does it mean something else? And, what does the morning star have to do with it?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about interpreting song lyrics. In context, it means, like, *nothing much*.

Comment: The night is gone, as if it were washed away (presumably by the dawn). The "morning" star is any planet visible in morning daylight. There is a tradition to make a wish on an evening star, this is  a double twist on that. "mourning" because even the stars might be sad at what is happening

Comment: Is there a way to make it more generic? I am using this lyrics as an example for the usage.

Comment: Thanks @Brian. Would it be possible to move your comment to an answer so that I can accept it?

Comment: @Brian Hitchcock: Given it's ***song lyrics***, I think the *morning/mourning* wordplay is a bit pointless (if indeed OP has transcribed it correctly).

Comment: Yeah, @FumbleFingers is correct. Wishing on a morning star is something I didn't know about.

Comment: He transcribed correctly. The song title itself is "Mourning Star".

Comment: @Brian: Ah right. If it's in the *title*, obviously people are more likely to pick up on it.

Comment: @Pareham: Most of the Google hits for [*It's like meaningless*](https://www.google.co.uk/search?hl=en&source=hp&q=%22it%27s+like+meaningless%22&aq=f&aqi=g5g-z1g4&aql=&oq=&gs_rfai=&gws_rd=ssl#hl=en&q=%22it%27s+like+meaningless%22+-%22meaningless+sex%22) seem to be for the same meaningless "filler" usage.

Comment: @Brian: The idiomatic standard is just plain [*wish upon a star*](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=wish+upon+a+star%2Cwish+upon+a+morning+star%2Cwish+upon+an+evening+star&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cwish%20upon%20a%20star%3B%2Cc0). There's only ***one*** [written instance with "evening"](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22wish+upon+an+evening+star%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1&gws_rd=ssl) in the whole of Google Books (and another one for "morning").

Comment: Star light, star bright;  first star I see tonight; I wish I may, I wish I might; have this wish I wish tonight.

Comment: So maybe I should have said there WAS a tradition, when children were taught that nursery rhyme.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Like washed away" means that the night is gone, as if it had been washed away (presumably by the dawn).  A "morning star" (planet) was still visible in the early daylight. The author calls it a "mourning star". Judging by the sad tone of the other lyrics, the author might be suggesting that even the "star" was sad at what has been happening on Earth.